# I have a huge Graphic file and would like to create an overlay to Google Maps, do I have to create tiles?

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, overlay, android-mapview

I am currently working on an application that display a custom map (some artist of my city did it) and would like to create on overlay for the city in Google Maps.

So the user would be able to open a MapView with this overlay.

As the graphic file is really huge (12km * 7 km is about 75Mb in a medium/low definition), I succed to do it (here is the code):
http://www.androidsnippets.com/drawing-an-image-as-a-map-overlay2

```
   MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    MapController mapController = map.getController();
    List<Overlay> overlays = map.getOverlays();
    overlays.add(new DrawableMapOverlay(this, point, R.drawable.my_drawable);
    map.invalidate();
```

As the file is really heavy, the app is really slow.

How can I improve this, do I have to divide the map in Tiles?

Is there any idea/project that could help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to implement some sort of "lazyload" solution....now I havent worked with it much but this may be able to only load the parts of the image that the user is viewing instead of loading the whole thing at once. When the user moves then it will render the new area....I know you can do this with like an array of map markers...you may be able to use it to lazyload and image.  Check this out: [MapView Overlay Manager](http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/)

You may be able to modify the lazyloading method to work for you...

Comment: So, it seem quite logical that I will have to use tiles with your solution. Seem the best so far, but still not what I am looking for.

Comment: He is looking for a quadtree or a spatial index. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but http://www.maptiler.org/ is what you need.

Comment: That seem great for a desktop app... I just need to do the same thing in Android, or just create a webview.. Thank a lot for the link, I will investigate.

Comment: There are some packages like mapforge and osmdroid that can utilize locally stored tiles.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a tiling program yourself and use a spatial index or a space-filling-curve for the automatical tiling process. A si reduces the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. It looks like a quadtree and a fractal. There are some si like z-curve, peano curve or hilbert curve. I think you are free to choose your own si but Google for example uses a z-curve like most other mapping application. A si is used in many other problems likes heatmaps, treemaps, augmented reality, image comparsion, image compression. Especially the hilbert curve is useful because it traverse the 2d space in a recursive code, also known as the grey code that makes each adjacent tile address differ by only one bit and also it fills the space very good (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension). You want to look for Nick's hilbert curve spatial index quadtree blog. Disadvantage of the hilbert curve is that's a bit hard to implement and a tile is always of power of 2.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot load the file locally, you will need to use open source solutions like mapserver (mapserver.org) or geoserver.

I have experience with both, but tend to prefer mapserver.

You can load the graphics image there and have it rendered on the server and then use it on the device.

The good part of this solution is that you do not have to send the entire graphics file to the user. You can also enable the user to cache your 'tiles' (small pieces of 256x256 pixels that represent a portion of your big image file) so they do not need to fetch the content they are interested in again and again.

Loading the image locally is not a good idea if the map data is just too big. You have to split it up using maptiler (as mentioned in my previous answer) and then save the tiles (possibly in a zip file) and use a client like osmdroid to navigate it then.